# innerHTML gives me & as &amp; !

Tags: javascript

is there any JS (not jquery) method to get a URL from a span (ex: `<span id="h">http://x.com?d=d&x=x</span>`)

without the &'s changed to `&amp;s` ???

Thank you .

Comment: As discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/q/62577621 this issue applies even inside an href, not just in body text. This might not be obvious since I think it is not as widely known that `&amp;` is the more correct way to represent `&` in HTML, not just in body text, but even inside the contents of an href.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("h").textContent.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
```

(The replace calls are to trim leading and trailing white-space, which you may not need to do in your situation.)

Answer (score 4):

If you want a text representation of the data get the `.data` from the textNode instead of the `.innerHTML` of the HTML element.

```
var element = document.getElementById('h');
var textNode = element.firstChild;
var URI = textNode.data;
```

Using `.innerHTML` will give you the data in a form encoded for HTML (and browsers will correct the error you have in the original markup)

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can just use the following trick to decode the HTML entities:

```
function htmlDecode(input){
  var e = document.createElement('div');
  e.innerHTML = input;
  return e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}

htmlDecode("&lt;img src='myimage.jpg'&gt;"); 
// returns "<img src='myimage.jpg'>"
```

Answer (score 3):

If your HTML looks like this:

```
<div onclick="testClick()" id="h">http://x.com?d=d&x=x</div>
```

You can have a function that will log the innerText:

```
  function testClick() {
    console.log(event.target.innerText)
  }
```

This will give you the value:

```
http://x.com?d=d&x=x
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because the original HTML code is not valid, but was nevertheless correctly parsed as you intended, but printed as it should be. `&` is a special character in HTML, much like `<` is and you should encode them by the corresponding html entities.

Comment: Actually i don't want to PRINT them , i want to SET the src of an image using it , so it won't work if the &'s was changed to &amp;

Comment: I did originally vote this up, but while it explains *why* the behaviour is as it is, it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @Ronan - the src of the image should work fine with properly encoded ampersands (i.e. with &amp; instead of &).  Can you confirm that it does actually cause you a problem?

Comment: It shouldn't work if you are setting the `src` property with JavaScript.

Comment: @Dexter , yes it is not working . images on my site are loaded through image.php , so the & is used to send the ID of the image to be loaded , if it's &amp; the php script wont get the correct ID .

Comment: @Ronan: You ask for innerHTML, and thus HTML is what you get. If you want the data, ask for the data, as @David suggested. Nonetheless your HTML is not valid and you should fix that. Also from the little I can guess, it seems whatever it is you are doing will end up being quite fragile.

Comment: can you define "Not Valid" here ? i am using group of `SPAN` to store URIs to images and i need it to be a SPAN and not some javascript array , so what does "NOT VALID" mean here ? is it forbidden to put whatever you want into a `SPAN` ? what if i wanted to put the following text "xcserw4dadw3" will the HTML code of the page be "Not Valid" then ?

Comment: `<span id="h">http://x.com?d=d&x=x</span>` is not valid HTML, for the same reason `<span>&</span>` isn't, just like `<span><</span>` isn't. Special characters (`<`, `>` and `&`) do not represent themselves. `&` signifies the beginning of an html entity, and the character `&` must therefore be represented as `&amp;`. So in your case, `<span id="h">http://x.com?d=d&amp;x=x</span>` would be valid.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to get the literal text is with `.innerText`

Whereas using `.innerHTML` will encode chars like `&`.

So when I have a `<span>` like this:

```html
<span id="h">http://x.com?d=d&x=x</span>
```

I can do this:

```js
const spanSelector = document.querySelector("span #id")
const text = spanSelector.innerText
// text: http://x.com?d=d&x=x
```